# Using Node.js app in website

Tags: apache, node.js, web-applications

I'm building an app using Node.js. My question is:

Is it possible to use Node.js app in website that is running on Apache?

If yes, can you please tell me how?

Comment: why would you use apache after all if you've got node?

Answer (score 2):

[apache](/questions/tagged/apache) is a **WebServer**.

[node.js](/questions/tagged/node.js) is a platform that runs **JavaScript** and can be used to make network applications.

A minimal [node.js](/questions/tagged/node.js) web application (http server) would look like this:

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.end('Hello World!');
}).listen(80);
```

That means (generally) you don't need a **WebServer** to run you [node.js](/questions/tagged/node.js) application.

You should make a `http`/`https` server in your **node** app to handle client requests instead.

---

On the other hand, you can communicate with your **node** app from within the apps running on **Apache** and other **WebServers**.

There are several ways to do so, like using a [message-queue](/questions/tagged/message-queue), **(unix-)sockets**, **databases**, etc.